# How to create DB2 multiple Instance?

Tags: db2, chef-infra

I have response file which create one instance of DB2.

How to create multiple Db2 instances using the response file for silent installation of DB2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the response file you can define multiple instances. You have to define them as

```
INSTANCE                  = DB2_INS2        ** char(8)  no spaces
```

And then, define every single element for this instance

```
DB2_INS2.NAME             = db2inst1        ** char(8)  no spaces, no upper case letters
DB2_INS2.GROUP_NAME       = db2iadm1        ** char(30) no spaces
```

The work `DB2_INS2` is just a name in the response file, and it is not the name of the instance.

You can give any name. For another, it could be

```
INSTANCE                  = PROD        ** char(8)  no spaces
PROD.NAME             = db2inst1        ** char(8)  no spaces, no upper case letters
PROD.GROUP_NAME       = db2iadm1        ** char(30) no spaces
```

The response file has a section where it explain how to define multiple instances:

```
** 2nd (non-pureScale) Instance Creation Settings
** ----------------------------------------------
** Multiple (non-pureScale) DB2 instances can be created in the same
** installation. This section shows how to specify the 2nd instance in the rsp
** file. Note: Only a subset of the instance keywords are listed below. You can
** specify other instance related keywords similar as the 1st instance. All
** keywords in this section are commented out. By default, only one instance
** will be created during the install.
```

Comment: <%   node['xxxx'].each do |device| -%>

INSTANCE                       =#{node['xxxx']}
#{node['xxxx']}.NAME           = #{node['xxxx']}
#{node['xxxx']}.GROUP_NAME      = #{node['xxxx']}
#{node['xxxx']}.PORT_NUMBER           = 50000
#{node['xxxx']}.FCM_PORT_NUMBER       = 60000

here i want to increment the FCm number and PORT number increment for each value of instance  
Can u plz help me out

Comment: ,Do you have nay idea about above doubt (mentioned in above comment)

Comment: I do know the syntax you are using. Why do you can to create a file dynamically as response file? why don't you create the instances directly, that makes the process still more complex?

Comment: If user want to create 10 instance of DB2 with response file,then it will not be good to do manually by writing the same code again again ,insted of that it is better that he run for each loop where he pass all the instance name in loop  and create instance property for all that using the code

Comment: knife bootstrap -x " " -P " " -j {"instance":"inst1 inst2 inst3 inst4 inst5 "} like this when user run above command then using the for each loop in resposne file it will be good .

Answer (score 0):

The best guess would be to create a template.

Then in a recipe, create the files from the template with different parameters and notifies the executions from the resource.

Something like this (untested code, just to illustrate):

Attribute.rb

```
default['db2']['instances']['A']['port'] = 1234
default['db2']['instances']['A']['bind_adress'] = "*"
default['db2']['instances']['A']['password'] = "whatever"

default['db2']['instances']['B']['port'] = 1235
default['db2']['instances']['B']['bind_adress'] = "*"
default['db2']['instances']['B']['password'] = "whatever"
```

default.rb (recipe)

```
node['db2']['instances'].each do |id,properties|
  template "/path/to/db2_#{id}_answer" do
    source "answer_file.erb"
    notifies :run, "execute[install_db2_#{id}"
    variabes (
      vars => properties
    )
  end

  execute "install_db2_#{id}" do
    command "/path/to/script_to_init /path/to/db2_#{id}_answer"
    action :nothing
  end
end
```

Comment: This is not a DB2 response file. This does not answer what was asked.

Comment: @AngocA The Op question is how to do with chef, not knowing the format of the file I answered for the chef part. If chef is unneeded, there's a bad tag, waiting an Op comment before removing the answer.